# ruby method returns wrong elements with odd/even index ruby 2.6.0

Tags: ruby

```
def even_odd_array
  number = 5169294814153321
  array_odd_index = []
  array_even_index = []

  array_of_chars = number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
  array_of_chars.each { |x| array_of_chars.index(x) % 2 == 0 ? array_even_index << x : array_odd_index << x } <----- this returns wrong arrays
  #array_odd_index, array_even_index = array_of_chars.each_slice(2).to_a.transpose
  p array_even_index
  p array_odd_index  
end
```

array_even_index [5, 6, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2]

array_odd_index [1, 9, 9, 8, 1, 1, 1]

what's wrong with it and are there any other ways to make it?

Comment: Is the index of 5 in `array_of_chars` even? yes, is the index of 1 in `array_of_chars` even? no, is the index of 6 in `array_of_chars` even? yes..., so far the code looks to be doing what you want it to do. Better you can explain what you're trying to do and what is your expected output?

Comment: I expect to have 2 arrays. First array should have all the numbers with odd index, the other with even index

Comment: Isn't that what you currently have? Or are you mixing the `index` with something else?

Comment: "what's wrong with it" – That is not how [so] works. *You* need to tell *us* what's wrong, what you are trying to do, what you tried to fix the problem, where you got stuck, and what you have tried to get unstuck.

Comment: I expect this method to return 2 arrays. First should be like ``` array_even_index #[5, 6, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2]``` and the second ```array_odd_index #[1, 9, 9, 8, 4, 5, 3, 1]```. But it return arrays, that are in description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your actual code is that `index` returns the index of the first element it finds in the receiver. As 1 is 4 times in `number` it'll return the index of the first 1 in `number` from left to right, same for all other repeated numbers.

An easy solution; use `each_with_index` which allows you to iterate over each element in the receiver plus yielding the current index of that element, so you can check if the index is even or not, deciding where to push the element:

```
array_of_chars.each_with_index do |x, index|
  if index.even?
    array_even_index << x
  else
    array_odd_index << x
  end
end
```

---

Or you can use `partition` plus `with_index` for that:

```
array_even_index, array_odd_index = 5169294814153321.digits.reverse.partition.with_index { |_, index| index.even? }
p array_even_index # [5, 6, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2]
p array_odd_index # [1, 9, 9, 8, 4, 5, 3, 1]
```